# Method to get a summary view from a dataset

Tags: linq

I have a dataset that looks like this:

Date
Category
Rate
Quantity

There will be 0 or 1 row for each Category for any given Date.

What is a good way to get this data into a summary type of view?

For example:

Date
Category1_Rate
Category2_Rate
Category3_Rate
Category4_Rate

I have a fixed number of Categories.

I'm using linq.

Here is an example.  If I have this data:

```
Date    Category    Rate    Quantity  
1/1/12  toys        15      12  
1/1/12  games       20      20  
1/1/12  dvds        18      30  
1/2/12  toys        19      13  
1/2/12  dvds        20      17
```

I want to produce a summary that looks like this:

```
Date     toys_rate   games_rate   dvds_rate  
1/1/12   15          20           18  
1/2/12   19          null         20
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly something like this

```
var summarydata = 
    from r in table 
    group r by r.Date into g 
    select new 
    { 
        Date = g.Key,
        ToysRate = g.Where(e=> e.Category == "toys").Count() > 0 ? 
                       (int?)g.Where(e=> e.Category == "toys").First().Rate : null,
        GamesRate = g.Where(e=> e.Category == "games").Count() > 0 ? 
                       (int?)g.Where(e=> e.Category == "games").First().Rate : null,
        DvdsRate = g.Where(e=> e.Category == "dvds").Count() > 0 ? 
                       (int?)g.Where(e=> e.Category == "dvds").First().Rate : null
    };
```

Note I haven't tested this as I don't current have access to a C# environment.

**EDIT** - Added nullable int casts to properly set the type of the various rate fields in the resulting anonymous type.